# Is it possible to use move_upload_file with mod_rewrite on?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, upload

I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to my index in my website. I need to implement a feature to upload files/images but it's not working

```
$config_upload = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/";
$ext = getExt($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $config_upload.rand().$ext);
```

Since I'm using mod_rewrite this is not working at all. My "files" directory has 777 permissions. But I think mod_rewrite is messing up this relative path and the function is not working.

Do you have any idea how to fix it? I was thinking about limiting my mod rewrite for php files only

My current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js)/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` **does not** affects file uploading

Comment: is there any way I can troubleshoot what is going on then? I tried several different configurations, and I have no idea what else I can try

Comment: Do not use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] which is related to your server and not your app. For instance if your app is a vhost or in a subfolder it's probablly not the path you are looking for. Instead store the root path of your app in a config file (or elswhere)

Comment: Not directly related but this (`$config_upload.rand().$ext`) **WILL** cause file overwrites. use `uniqid()` instead of `rand()`

Answer (score 0):

php doesn't care or know about your mod rewrite.

just debug your php file.

Are you sure you got `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` and `$config_upload.rand().$ext` correctly? output them to double check.